# syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''

Tags: bash

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my program pls? It seems correct to me? Tx

Program:

```
foo = "https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/hott/notes/notes_week"
bar = "https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/hott/notes/notes_week"
for i in {1..12} 
do
    foo = $bar
    foo+="$i"+".pdf"
    wget foo
done
```

Input:

```
PS E:\book> wsl ./s.sh
```

Output:

```
./s.sh: line 1: foo: command not found
./s.sh: line 2: bar: command not found
./s.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/s.sh: line 4: `do
```

Comment: Assignments cannot have spaces between the variable name and the value: `foo="https://www...`, and there is no `+` or `+=` operator for strings in sh.  Try pasting your script [here](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to help catch common errors.

Comment: I also recommend running your script through `dos2unix`.